# Changing class on active Tab

Tags: css, angularjs, tabs, angular-ui-bootstrap

i have used angular UI tabs and i have buttons that switches to different tabs.
I am trying to change the style of a button of that tab whenever that same tab is active. so i used ng-class to change the styles.

i have the function inside scope which returns the active tab

```
 $scope.getActive = function() {
     return tabSelector.active;
    console.log("active tab = " + tabSelector.active);

 }
```

this function returns the number 0,1,2 or 3 depending which tab is active

this is are my css classes

```
.btn-white-hollow {
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    margin-top: 16px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #0A135E;
    font-weight: bolder;
    -webkit-transition: all linear .2s;
    transition: all linear .2s;
}

.btn-white-hollow-selected {
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    margin-top: 16px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #fd7400;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fd7400;
    background: #fff;

}
```

i tried using ng class in this format but it will not work .

```
 <li class="seekerhead" >
    <button  type="button" ng-class= { 'btn-white-hollow-selected' : getActive() == '0', 'btn-white-hollow' : getActive!== '0' }>Ask a Question
    </button>
</li>
```

The problem is ghat the ng-class is not picking up the css classes.
I even tried  `getActive!== 0` but that does not work either
how do i make it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if the given code misses some information, you should be able to achieve what you are looking for just following this code.
Define inside your controller an active variable attached to the scope, initialized to the variable of the panel that you want to be the one active by default.

`$scope.activeTab = 1; //supposing you want the first one to be enabled`

Then in your HTML code of your tabs use the following code: 

`<button  type="button" ng-class="{ 'btn-white-hollow-selected' : activeTab === 1, 'btn-white-hollow' : activeTab !== 1 }" ng-click="activeTab = 1">
    Ask a Question
</button>`

This supposing that the button you posted is the one corresponding to the tab.

Comment: so i tried this and it works 
 `<li> active tab is {{activeTab}} </li>
        <li><button  type="button"  ng-class= { activeTab === 0 ? 'btn-whor-hollow-selected' : 'btn-whor-hollow' }  ng-click="selectTab(0))">Ask a Question</button></li>`

this shows me that active tabs are changing to 0,1,2 whenever i change the tabs. but it still will not pick up the style class.

I simply tried writing true instead of condition but it still wont pick up the css class

Comment: You missed the the `"` wrapping the ng-class
p.s. Sorry I just saw that formatting the code the `"` were removed also in my first answer.
Updated the answer including that as well